# How do I use std::enable_if with a self-deducing return type?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, type-traits, c++14, enable-if

[C++14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++14#Function_return_type_deduction) will have functions whose return type can be deduced based on the return value.

```
auto function(){
    return "hello world";
}
```

Can I apply this behaviour to functions that use [enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) for the SFINAE by return type idiom?

For example, let's consider the following two functons:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

//This function is chosen when an integral type is passed in
template<class T >
auto function(T t) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type {
    std::cout << "integral" << std::endl;
    return;
}

//This function is chosen when a floating point type is passed in
template<class T >
auto function(T t) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type{
    std::cout << "floating" << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main(){

  function(1);    //prints "integral"
  function(3.14); //prints "floating"

}
```

As you can see, the correct function is chosen using the SFINAE by return type idiom.
However, these are both void functions.  The second parameter of `enable_if` is default set to `void`. This would be the same:

```
//This function is chosen when an integral type is passed in
template<class T >
auto function(T t) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, void>::type {
    std::cout << "integral" << std::endl;
    return;
}

//This function is chosen when a floating point type is passed in
template<class T >
auto function(T t) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, void>::type{
    std::cout << "floating" << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

Is there something I can do to these two functions, so that their return type is deduced by the return value?

gcc 4.8.2 (using `--std=c++1y`)

Answer (score 14):

`std::enable_if` doesn't have to be in the return type, as of C++11 it can be part of the template parameters.

So your equivalent functions can be (or, well, something to this effect):

```
enum class enabler_t {};

template<typename T>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<T::value, enabler_t>::type;

//This function is chosen when an integral type is passed in
template<class T, EnableIf<std::is_integral<T>>...>
auto function(T t) {
    std::cout << "integral" << std::endl;
    return;
}

//This function is chosen when a floating point type is passed in
template<class T, EnableIf<std::is_floating_point<T>>...>
auto function(T t) {
    std::cout << "floating" << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

It can also be a parameter in the function:

```
//This function is chosen when an integral type is passed in
template<class T>
auto function(T t, EnableIf<std::is_integral<T>>* = nullptr) {
    std::cout << "integral" << std::endl;
    return;
}

//This function is chosen when a floating point type is passed in
template<class T>
auto function(T t, EnableIf<std::is_floating_point<T>>* = nullptr) {
    std::cout << "floating" << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

This will keep the automatic type deduction and SFINAE.

Comment: I don't understand the "..." in the first example.  Does that somehow give a value to enabler_t?

Comment: @TrevorHickey, no, it declares a non-type template parameter pack that accepts zero or more arguments of type `enabler_t`. In practice when you call `function(x)` the parameter pack will be deduced to be empty (in which case the call will be ambiguous, so the first example doesn't work).

Comment: @JonathanWakely Works how I expect it to in GCC but not in Clang because Clang doesn't accept non-type template parameter packs as far as I know. Though in practice I usually set up `DisableIf`s or negate the previous condition of the other `EnableIf`s.

Comment: The above use of variadic templates with `EnableIf` will get in the way if a function instead has multiple arguments. In this case try `EnableIf<std::is_integral<T>> = enabler_t{}` instead.

Comment: I still don't like these solutions. Yes, I do care about the programmer who mistakenly calls `function<float,enabler_t{}>(42)`.

Comment: @user2023370 you are not making sense. The compiler won't let you do that, and how does one "mistakenly" write code like that?

Comment: Why do we need the `* = nullptr` for the `enable_if`?

Comment: What is the purpose of `enabler_t`? It works for me without any type: `template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type...> auto foo() { return T(); }`

Answer (score 7):

`std::enable_if` can be a return type, a function parameter, or a template parameter. You will get a function redefinition error if you use return type or template parameter, so you need to use `std::enable_if` as a function parameter:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, void>::type>
auto function(T t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, void>::type* dummy = nullptr) {
    std::cout << "integral" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

//This function is chosen when a floating point type is passed in
template<class T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, void>::type>
auto function(T t, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, void>::type* dummy = nullptr) {
    std::cout << "floating" << std::endl;
    return 0.0f;
}

int main() 
{
    auto ret = function(0); // integral
    auto ret2 = function(0.0f); // floating
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_integral<decltype(ret)>::value << std::endl; // true
    std::cout << std::is_floating_point<decltype(ret2)>::value << std::endl; // true
}
```

Comment: +1. This solution is better than the one proposed by @Rapptz: in this solution there is no need for an additional class, and it compiles both in gcc and clang.

Comment: Riding on this solution, adding a more simple version in which the enable_if appears only as a template parameter and not as a method argument.

Answer (score 3):

In the line of the answer by @user1508519, we can remove the enable_if parameter from the method and keep it only as a template parameter.
We rely on the fact that `enable_if<false>` doesn't define `type`, so `enable_if<false>::type`, which doesn't exist, is a good tool for SFINAE -- in the method signature, which includes the template parameters.

**There is no need to actually use this template parameter in the method itself!**

Thus:

```
template<class T,
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* dummy = nullptr>
auto function(T t) {
    std::cout << "integral" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

// This function is chosen when a floating point type is passed in
template<class T, 
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type* dummy = nullptr>
auto function(T t) {
    std::cout << "floating" << std::endl;
    return 0.0f;
}

int main() {
    auto ret = function(0); // integral
    auto ret2 = function(0.0f); // floating
    cout << std::boolalpha;
    cout << std::is_integral<decltype(ret)>::value << endl; // true
    cout << std::is_floating_point<decltype(ret2)>::value << endl; // true
}
```

### Output

```
integral
floating
true
true
```

Comment: This is just working because of template overload resolution : https://godbolt.org/z/4vdvePGx1.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere `std::enable_if` can be used to form either a return type; a function parameter; or a template parameter.

However, the latter two methods have the disdvantage that they change the signature of the relevant function or object. Using `std::enable_if` at the return type, on the other hand, leaves the function and template parameter count unchanged.

With the automatic inference of lambda return types in C++11 (likely extended to normal functions in C++14) it would be ideal if there was a technique to both have the return type inferred; *and* use `std::enable_if` on the return type. To have your cake an eat it - almost. Alas it seems that this is currently impossible.