# SFINAE together with auto-deduced return type and variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization, sfinae

In this topic, we learn how to use SFINAE together with auto/self-deduced return type:
[How do I use std::enable_if with a self-deducing return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709896/how-do-i-use-stdenable-if-with-a-self-deducing-return-type)

However, it seems I cannot apply any of the techniques when I'm also using a variadic template. Here's my signature:

```
template<typename Scalar, class ClassDispatcher, typename... Args>
auto dispatch(Args&&... args) {}
```

And I would like to specialize on the Scalar template using SFINAE. But since the Scalar argument doesn't appear in the argument list, I find it hard to use enable_if anywhere. And because of the parameter pack, I can't add dummy arguments to the argument list nor the template argument list. The last place is the return type, but as said I would like to keep it as auto. Any ideas?

Comment: Have this function forward to a helper function that takes a dummy `Scalar` pointer (you can just always pass `nullptr`), and specialize that one.

Comment: "I can't add dummy arguments to the...template argument list" that's not true.

Comment: @T.C. Please show this then. If i do something like this: `template<typename Scalar, class ClassDispatcher, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Scalar, float>::value>::type, typename... Args>` I get errors about not being able to deduce the type for "__formal"

Comment: and @IgorTandetnik this works, thanks! Not the prettiest solution but I'm happy it doesn't change the interface - I'm just stuffing it away in a detail namespace.

Answer (score 1):

(Old question, but answering it for those who find this.)

Add a type template parameter with a default argument based on `std::enable_if` at the end of the template parameter list, and make the default argument dependent on the deduced `Args` by using a comma expression dependent on `Args` even if you don't care about `Args`, and then add any tests you want on `Scalar`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Scalar, class ClassDispatcher, typename... Args,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Args), std::is_same<Scalar, float>::value)>::type>
auto dispatch(Args&&... args) {}
```

The key is that for SFINAE to work, the default template argument must *depend* on *deduced* template arguments, even if only in a comma expression whose result isn't affected by the actual deduced template arguments.